# How to extend a function in JavaScript with a lot of methods?

Tags: javascript, oop, coffeescript, extends

I am trying to extend the `https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github` object and using `CoffeeScript`, doing something like:

```
class GitHubETag extends GitHubApi
  constructor: (defaults = {}) ->
    doStuff()
```

However, the `GitHubApi` has a lot of methods that I want to expose in my `GitHubETag` object, but I want to do some logic BEFORE calling the `GitHubApi` version.

As an example:

```
github = new GitHubETag()
github.repos.get query, (err, response) ->
  doStuff()
```

I don't want to have to explicitly define the `repos` and `get` object/function in my `GitHubETag`. I want to do some logic and THEN call the `repos` and `get` object/function of `GitHubApi`.

How would I do this?

Comment: Read about the [decorator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need [super](http://coffeescript.org/#classes):

```
class Animal
  constructor: (@name) ->

  move: (meters) ->
    alert @name + " moved #{meters}m."

class Horse extends Animal
  move: ->
    alert "Galloping..." # <--- put in your logic before calling super
    super 45
```

Comment: But that assume I want to define the `move` function in `Horse`. What if I wanted to apply some logic before `Horse.anyFunction` where `anyFunction` is in `Animal`?

Comment: you could do logic in the constructor, before calling super in the constructor. That would give you the hook to setup before any other function on the prototype is called. if you want to do work within the method itself before the parent method is called, you need to redefine the method in your child class and call super like shown above..

Comment: Yep, I agree with Jed. If you don't want to define `move` then you need a different base class (i.e. why are you using that base class?).